# What is QJackCtl?

Tags: sound, 18.04, ubuntu-studio, jack

Does Jack just make the audio better when I run it or how does it work?

I have Ubuntu Studio 18.04.

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y Problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/271411). What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Please avoid asking multiple questions at once. Moreover, Google can answer your first question easily. https://qjackctl.sourceforge.io/

Answer (score 2):

"QjackCtl is a simple Qt application to control the JACK sound server daemon ..."

These pages explain it.

[QjackCtl Jack Audio Connection Kit](https://qjackctl.sourceforge.io/)
and
[JACK Audio Connection Kit](http://jackaudio.org/)